# Filtering unique results from and already filtered list in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a an array with objects looking like this:

```
{
"date":"11/11/2014",
"time":"17.20.37",
"car":"396",
"driver":"Jenny",
"from":"Old Office",
"destination":"Log WH",
"pax":"3","comment":"",
"commenttime":"",
"arrival":"17.20.48",
"inserted":true,
"cancelled":"",
"duration":"00:00:11"
}
```

Once I have a considerable amount of data, I want to be able to show statistics based on this data.
Something like:

November 2014
Car: 1, Number of trips: X, Time on the road: Y
Car: 2, Number of trips: X, Time on the road: Y
...

October 2014
Car: 4, Number of trips: X, Time on the road: Y
Car: 2, Number of trips: X, Time on the road: Y
...

I've been able to list the unique month objects like this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.recordlist, function(record) {
  var month = moment(record.date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('MMMM YYYY');
  monthDict[month] = monthDict[month] || [];
  monthDict[month].push(record);
});

for (record in monthDict) {     

    for (item in monthDict[record]) {
        monthDict[record][item]['month'] = moment(record.date).format('MMMM YYYY');        
    }

};

$scope.monthlist = monthDict;
console.log($scope.monthlist);
```

This produces the following object:

```
Object
  November 2014: Array[5]
    0: Object
      arrival: "17.21.27"
      cancelled: ""
      car: "396"
      comment: ""
      commenttime: ""
      date: "11/11/2014"
      destination: "Gumbo Market"
      driver: "Erik"
      duration: "00:00:17"
      from: "Luna House"
      inserted: true
      month: "November 2014"
      pax: "3"
      time: "17.21.10"
      totalduration: "00:00:38"
      totaldurationdriver: "00:00:17"
    Object1: 
    Object2: 
    Object3: 
    Object4: 
  October 2014: Array[1]
    0: Object
      ...
```

On the view I show it like this:

```
    <div ng-repeat="(key,val) in monthlist">
      <div class="row msf-top-row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          {{key}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This already produces a list of the unique months coming from the initial object list.

Now, given that every array in monthlist is a trip, I want to do the same kind of filtering for unique properties inside every month/year object, so I'm able to list the cars (car : "") that travelled on each month, how many trips they took, an the total duration on the road for each of them (totalduration = "HH.mm.ss").

So basically I want to filter unique elements from a list of already filtered unique elements.

Any pointer on how to proceed? My brain is spinning just thinking about it..

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

```
$scope.uniqueMonths = [];

angular.forEach($scope.recordlist, function(record) {
    var month = moment(record.date, 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('MMMM YYYY');

    if( typeof $scope.uniqueMonths[month] == 'undefined'){
         $scope.uniqueMonths[month] = {
                numberOfCars : 0,
                numberOfTrips : 0,
                timeOnTheRoad: 0,
                cars : {}
        };
    }

/**
* Add car type into the month if does not exist
**/
if(typeof $scope.uniqueMonths[month].cars[record.car] == 'undefined'){
    $scope.uniqueMonths[month].cars = {record.car : 1};
    $scope.uniqueMonths[month].numberOfCars++;
}

/**
* Increment number of trips since every object implies a 'trip'
**/
    $scope.uniqueMonths[month].numberOfTrips++;

/**
* Increment the time of seconds on the road. 
* Needs to convert to whole value integer.
**/

    $scope.uniqueMonths[month].timeOnTheRoad = $filter('secondsFmt')(record.duration);

});
```

In filter.js

```
angular.module('myapp', []).filter('secondsFmt', function(){
    return function(time) {
        var totalSeconds = 0;
        var times = time.split(':');
        totalSeconds += parseInt(times[0]) * 3600;
        totalSeconds += parseInt(times[1]) * 60;
        totalSeconds += parseInt(times[2]);
    return totalSeconds;
    };
});
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Just one comment: I don't need to show the number of cars, but the stats for each specific car code in the objects (e.g: "car":"396"). About the time, all time properties in the object are momentJS objects, so I can manipulate them easily. I'll give a try to your code tomorrow anyway, if the first part works, maybe I can figure out the rest myself. Thanks!!

Comment: If you want to filter by "car":"396", change the $scope.uniqueMonths[month] to $scope.uniqueMonth[car] and make month unique by doing a typeof undefined check.